# jquery.event.drop filtering drop target when use tolerance

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery

i use [jquery.event.drag/drop](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop) to fully reorder a tree

for reordering i use a custom "tolerance" function based on [this demo](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/reorder)

when tree is small all work perfect, but with some data (>2k) it's slow as hell

as tree open and close node, real drop target is usually ~50 but the code does not want filter and still compute at each cursor move on the 2k elements ..

i try some method to filter available drop target, but without any succes

by exemple into dropinit event :

```
return $(this).is( $availableDrop );
```

or set filter option in $.drop options

```
filter:".validdrop"
```

i curently return 0; in the tolerance function when the current element isn't an allowed one ...

it's ~~~~ usable but still slow as hell

i [set up a fiddle with minimum thing](http://jsfiddle.net/saBN6/17/), *Help me Obi Wan Kenobi you're my only hope*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it was cause of the full "live", extract all into dedicated function and use a classic init on initial element and future one work great.

```
$.fn.initDrag = function(){
    $(this).drag('init',draginit).drag('start',dragstart).drag('end',dragend).drag(indrag).drop('init',dropinit);
};

$(selector).initDrag();
```

[fast version fiddle :)](http://jsfiddle.net/saBN6/19/)